# Incorrect MSM system folder path?

Tags: multi-site-manager, path

I have recently purchased MSM but am having trouble getting it to work. I have [followed the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/createsite.html) to a tee but have had no luck.

I have completed the following:

1. Installed and activated the add-on
2. Created a new site (did not copy anything from site 1)
3. Updated URL to root directory in Admin > General Config
4. Created a new template group and made default for site2
5. Added site 2 to hosting
6. Ensured "open_basedir" has been turned off
7. Copied admin.php & index.php from site 1
8. Updated system path in admin.php & index.php to absolute URL of site 1 (other variables also updated to reflect site 2 cp url & url).
9. Uploaded admin.php & index.php to site 2
10. Reload the site but get the following message:

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please
>   open the following file and correct this: index.php

I have tried relative links for system paths but get the same result.

Does the name of site 2's admin.php & system name need to be the same as site 1 (I have changed it as a [security precaution](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/best_practices.html)) ?

Any help of feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

The crucial part of MSM is the "$system_path" variable in index/admin.php which is the (file) system path of site 1's system folder rather than a URL.

> 8) Updated system path in admin.php & index.php to **absolute URL** of
>   site 1 (other variables also updated to reflect site 2 cp url & url).

From what you wrote I'm not sure if you've got that part right - on shared hosting it can be tricky figuring out what that path is?

If you are still getting the error I'd suggest trying a plain old php file system include to check that you have the permissions etc correct.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your response. I have tried both relative & absolute with no lock. After speaking in depth with my host (Eleven2.com) they said the relative url should be: ../../username/public_html however this did not work. Do you have an example of the "plain old php file system include to check that you have the permissions etc correct"?

Comment: @dan <?php include "/path/to/site1/system/index.php"; ?> call it test.php, save it in site 2 & run it. You should get an "Your system folder path does not appear...." error.  If not - there's your problem.

Comment: @dan also to see what the path should be, on site 1 <?php print $_SERVER['script_filename']; ?> should tell you the absolute path.

Comment: Hi @jon, thanks for your feedback. I tried <?php print $_SERVER['script_filename']; ?> on site1 (test.php) but nothing printed. I have spoken further with my host & they said: "It seems that domain2 account cannot access the other account's path since they are separate cpanel accounts. I would suggest you to try creating domain2 as addon domain under the domain1 for creating multisite". So, I deleted the separate account I originally set up and added site2 as an add-on domain. I can access the MSM EE content through site1.com.au/site2.com.au but if I try site2.com.au I get a 404. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you resolve this?